# Can't understand why my nested php foreach loop is not updating values as expected

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, reference

Have revised my original code. However am still not managing to actually update my original array. When I echo out `echo '<pre>'.print_r( $form['fields'][8]['choices'][0]['text'] ).'</pre>';` I am still getting my original array values. Not much of a programmer so thrashing around in the dark a bit.

```
$form_id = '6';
$form = GFAPI::get_form( $form_id );

foreach ( $form['fields'] as $key => &$field )
{
    if (isset( $field['id']) && $field['id'] == 47 )
    {
        foreach ( $field['choices'] as $key => &$choice )
        {
            if (isset($choice['value']) && $choice['value'] == 1)
            {
                $choice['text'] = 'test';
                $choice['price'] = '99';

                echo '<pre>'.print_r( $choice['text']).'</pre>';
                echo '<pre>'.print_r( $choice['price']).'</pre>';
            }
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r( $form['fields'][8]['choices'][0]['text'] ).'</pre>';

$result = GFAPI::update_form( $form );
return $result;
```

Comment: This question appears to be Off-topic: Cannot Reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
foreach ($choices as $key => $choice)
```

Creates a *copy* of the array stored in `$choices[$key]`, and `$choice` refers to that, and not to inside the original `$choices` array.

If you change it to creating `$choice` by reference, it should work:

```
foreach ($choices as $key => &$choice)
```

But I don't recommend to do that, because there can be subtle side effects in some situations that can be hard to find.

UPDATE:

I tested with this code:

```
$form = [
    "fields" => [
        8 => [
            "id" => 47,
            "choices" => [
                0 => [
                    "value" => 1,
                    "text" => "original text",
                    "price" => "original price",
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

foreach ( $form['fields'] as $key => &$field )
{
    if (isset( $field['id']) && $field['id'] == 47 )
    {
        foreach ( $field['choices'] as $key => &$choice )
        {
            if (isset($choice['value']) && $choice['value'] == 1)
            {
                $choice['text'] = 'test';
                $choice['price'] = '99';

                echo "<pre>in-loop text: {$choice["text"]}</pre>";
                echo "<pre>in-loop price: {$choice["price"]}</pre>";
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>out-of-loop text: {$form['fields'][8]['choices'][0]['text']}</pre>";
```

The output I got seems to be what I think you expect:

```
in-loop text: test
in-loop price: 99
out-of-loop text: test
```

If this is not what you expect then I may have misunderstood the question...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have modified the code as above inline with your suggestion, but am still not getting what I need. Possibly I am misunderstanding what I am trying to do.

Comment: I see. Give me a minute to try it myself.

Comment: @phantomdentist I updated my answer with my test and results. Please see.

Comment: Thanks for that. Help much appreciated. Even with that code I still get the original vaue out of the loop so I assume it's likely related to something to do with the plugin I am working with (gravity forms). This has given me what I need to know to contact their support however, so thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are updating $choices[$key]['text'] value so you can get $choices[$key]['text'].

You need to update value of $choice['text']. Basically you have no need of $key in you foreach loop. This $key can be used if you need to filter data based on key like $key == "some value".

See the updated code

```
$fields = $form['fields'];
foreach ($fields as $key => $field)
{
    if (isset($fields[$key]['id']) && $fields[$key]['id'] == 47)
    {
        $choices = $fields[$key]['choices'];
        foreach ($choices as $key => $choice)
        {
            if (isset($choice['value']) && $choice['value'] == 1)
            {
                $choice['text'] = 'test';
                $choice['price'] = '99';
                echo '<pre>'.print_r( $choice['text']).'</pre>';
                echo '<pre>'.print_r( $choice['price']).'</pre>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I believe the issues is actually related to the way the plugin I am working with deals with things, as even could that generally does the job does not do so here. Thanks for the help none the less.